# Is there any alternative for DB calls inside loop?

Tags: java, database, performance, for-loop

I am facing performance problems due to thousands of DB calls inside a for loop. 
Is there any way out?

```
for( String cacheKey : moduleCacheMap.keySet() )
    {
        if( inputCachekey != null && inputCachekey.equalsIgnoreCase( cacheKey ) )
        {
            CacheItemDto cacheItemDto = moduleCacheMap.get( cacheKey ) ;
            cacheList = cacheDao.getCacheList( cacheItemDto ) ;
        }
    }
```

Here `cacheDao.getCacheList` is firing a new database transaction each time.

Answer (score 1):

1) Fetch all the needed rows in a single query instead of looping, or

2) Make a lazy loading cacheList if you don't need all the data immediately.

Comment: Option 1 is not possible since I need to get cacheItemDto fetched from database based on cacheKey got from moduleCacheMap.keySet()

Comment: Nothing in that statement rules it as impossible. Databases do not care where you have your stuff. Just SELECT all of it and parse it when you get it.